# Create Store in magento

Tags: magento2

Hi I'm trying to create a website, store and store view in Magento 2. I've been watching youtube video on how to do it. But I'm just curious why is it my admin panel has this kind of prefix

[image]

As you can see below my website name I have (Code: aliexpress) may I know what this mean? In the video I'm watching they don't have this. Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Every website, store and store view has one unique identifier that is called **code**. in your case your website Name is **Aliexpress** according to that name code is **aliexpress**.

Website code is helpful when we want to run specific website in Multi-Website environment. you can open your `index.php` file in your Magento installation directory and find the below code.

```
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = '<your website code>';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
```

Using above code you can run specific website.